# Easy way to create a reversed key list of TDictionary<TKey,TValue>?

Tags: delphi, generics, collections

Is there a simple way to take the key list of a [`TDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary) and reverse its order?

I could use a classic for I := ... loop but as I see there is [`TList<T>.Reverse`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/de/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Reverse) in Generics.Collections maybe there is a better / shorter way.

---

Update: a for I := downto loop will have the same useless order so the best way is using a separate `TList<TKey>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keys in a TDictionary are unordered. The class makes no guarantee over their order and the actual order that is used is not the order in which they are added. Reversing the order of an unordered dictionary is a meaningless operation.

Delphi does not come with an ordered dictionary class although there are third party classes available. If your usage is relatively simple you may be able to manage with an extra list containing the keys in the desired order.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use the TDictionary < Tkey, TValue >.**TKeyCollection** class.

```
function compareKeyReverse(const L, R: TKey): Integer;
begin
  // Reverse compare keys
  // if TKey = String, uncomment code below
  // Result := - SysUtils.CompareText(L, R);
end;

function getReverseSortedKeyArray(dictionary: TDictionary<TKey, TValue>): TArray<TKey>;
var
  keyArray: TArray<TKey>;
  keyCollecttion: TDictionary<Tkey, TValue>.TKeyCollection;
begin
  keyCollecttion:= TDictionary<Tkey, TValue>.TKeyCollection.Create(dictionary);
  try
    keyArray:= valueCollecttion.ToArray;
    TArray.Sort<Tkey>(keyArray, TComparer<Tkey>.Construct(compareKeyReverse));
  finally
    keyCollecttion.Free;
  end;

  Result := keyArray;
end;
```

Example of use :

```
var
  key: TKey;
  keyArray : TArray<TKey>;
begin
    keyArray  := getReverseSortedKeyArray (dictionary);
    for key in keyArray  do
    begin
      // ...
    end;
end;
```